# writing gzip csv file introduces random chars in the first row

Tags: python, csv, gzip

I am writing some csv data to a csv gzip file in python as follows

```
import csv
import gzip
import io

csv_rows=[["cara","vera","tara"],["rar","mar","bar"],["jump","lump","dump"]]
mem_file = io.BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=mem_file,mode="wb") as gz:
   with io.TextIOWrapper(gz, encoding='utf-8') as wrapper:
       writer = csv.writer(wrapper)
       writer.writerows(csv_rows)
       gz.write(mem_file.getvalue())
gz.close()
mem_file.seek(0)
```

When I gunzip the file the first column in the first row is a strange set of characters and causes
the first row to actually have 4 columns
The 2nd and 3rd rows are ok

I have tried different data and always see this behavior in the first column of the first row.
What is wrong with the code?

For reference here it is what I see in the gunzipped file

```
?‹? #,eÿcara,vera,tara 
rar,mar,bar 
jump,lump,dump
```

Comment: Could you post the byte representation of the extra character you have.

Comment: _When I gunzip the file_ I don't see any code here that would gunzip a file.  Can you show that code please.  In fact I don't see **any** code that actually writes to a file...?  How is an actual file being written at all?  This is all memory IO stuff as far as I can see, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @jlandercy I updated the post but it is a bit hard to reproduce it

Comment: @JohnGordon I just use `gunzip file` in the terminal

Comment: But what is the **actual file** you are gunzipping?  What is the **actual filename**? This code does not write to an actual filename, as far as I can see.  Whatever file you are gunzipping did not come from this code...

Comment: `gz.writer(mem_file.getValue())` -- is that right? I get an `AttributeError`. Do test the examples of your code before you actually post them. | It's also rather suspect that your writing into the gzip file, while you still have the `TextIOWrapper` using it as well. Are you sure there's no caching happening?

Comment: @DanMašek It is `gz.write`. Thanks. I fixed the post.

Comment: You told `gzip` to use the file object `mem_file`, then you told csv to write into the `gz`, and then you are trying to write the contents of `mem_file` to the zip.  That's a tangled web that cannot be right.

Comment: Even couriouser... why are you reading from the `BytesIO` that GZIp is currently in the process of writing to, and writing the result back to it through `wrapper+gz`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Good point. This is the first time I try to write csv to a gzip in python and it is likely I misunderstood how to do it.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes I might be wrong as this is the first time I try to write a csv to gzip file in python.

Comment: In fact, what you're seeing at the beginning of the file is `b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xb1\x1e,e\x02\xff'`, which is a 10 byte GZip file header, which is the only thing output so far. Since `TextIOWrapper` is still open, it hasn't flushed anything, so the header ends up the first thing compressed. (Which is why the order of things in the file is opposite to the order of function calls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line:

```py
gz.write(mem_file.getvalue())
```

(also it is`getvalue()`, not `getValue()`). The `csv.writer()` already uses `io.TextIOWrapper` to write to `gzip.GzipFile`, so there's no need to write to it again.

Answer (score 3):

Delete this line:

```
    gz.write(mem_file.getvalue())
```

and you will find this all works just fine.  The csv module will write into the gzip object, and gzip will write into the BytesIO object.  You don't need this extra step.